# Multiple lowess lines by column category in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm working with a subset of the NHANES dataset.  I've made a scatter plot that's plotting one column in my dataframe (RIAGENDR, gender- 1 is male, 2 is female) by WDIFF (Difference between self reported and measured weight.  I'm trying to create two lowess lines, one for men and one for female.  Here is my code:

```
#RIAGENDR 1= MALE,RIAGENDR 2= FEMALE 
finaldf2$color[finaldf2$RIAGENDR==1]= 'red'
finaldf2$color[finaldf2$RIAGENDR==2]= 'blue'
plot(finaldf2$WDIFF~ finaldf2$BMXWT, cex=0.8,
     pch = 20,
     col=finaldf2$color, ylim=c(-10,10),
     ylab="Difference btwn measured and self reported wgt", xlab="Measured wgt(kg)",
     main= "Measured vs Self-reported wgt, by gender")
legend(180, 10, c("Men", "Women"), pch = 20, cex= 0.8, col = c("red","blue"))
lines(lowess(finaldf2$BMXWT, finaldf2$WDIFF), col=finaldf2$color, lwd=3)
```

From this, I get this plot:
[image]

My issue is I can't figure out a way to have different lowess lines for the men and women.  I've tried a few versions of the last line, but I can only seem to get the one lowess line.  Does anybody have any experience creating two loweness lines from two categories within one column of a dataframe?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer:

```
plot(finaldf$BMXWT, finaldf2$WDIFF, pch= ".", ylim= c(-10, 10),
     col = ifelse(finaldf2$RIAGENDR==1, "red", "blue"),
     xlab = "Measured weight (kg)",
     ylab = "Difference btwn self-reported vs. measured wgt",
     main = "Measured wgt vs self-reported wgt by gender")
lines(lowess(finaldf$BMXWT[finaldf$RIAGENDR==1],
             finaldf2$WDIFF[finaldf2$RIAGENDR==1]),
      col= "red", lwd=1)
lines(lowess(finaldf2$BMXWT[finaldf2$RIAGENDR==2],
             finaldf2$WDIFF[finaldf2$RIAGENDR==2]),
      col = "blue", lwd=1)
legend(180, 10, c("Men", "Women"), pch = 20, cex= 0.8, col = c("red","blue"))
```

[image]